# Collect log Windows Defender for endpoint using elastic agent

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, event-viewer, windows-defender

How to collect logs windows Defender for endpoint or server using elastic agent ?

im already use "Microsoft Defender for Endpoint" (feature integration on elasticsearch) but i have to create a new azure application. so we need to collect logs only windows defender on laptop or PC

Thankyou

Configuration elastic agent for collect log windows defender endpoint laptop or PC

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.